# Attention on bountied question

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty

I have provided bounty on a question but it has not received much attention as expected. How do I draw attention apart from this??

The question is not mine but I desparately want to see an answer to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know any people who might be interested in the puzzle elsewhere, there's a handy "share" button under every post which provides a link for sharing the puzzle in your favourite medium. We also have some [chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=puzzling.stackexchange.com) where you could ask about a specific puzzle to get more eyes on it. And of course it's perfectly allowed to post another bounty on the question after a while if you feel it still hasn't garnered enough attention.